# How to add CMS directive {{block}} on custom module field in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, custom, cms-pages, template-directive

I have developed a custom slider for Magento 2. The fields for my slider in the backend are; Title, Image and Content. The Content is a Wysiwyg editor and I am trying to make it work like a CMS Page content where I can add codes like:

{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="new.template" template="mytemplate.phtml"}}

What classes do I need to call in my block constructor to output the same results as that of CMS pages?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: Still no. Any thoughts you have?

Comment: No, sorry also hoping to do something like this for simplicity. MazeStricks is definitely a move in the right direction. My idea is use his suggestion and call the block by code rather than an id which will probably change with migrations etc. Please tell me if you get it.

Comment: https://bit.ly/2BTcLJ5 using the link you can get CMS block result

Answer (score 1):

try to inject the class Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory in your constructor, Hope this helps.